# How to make client send many image files(.jpg) together to server in C++ using Winsock

Tags: c++, sockets

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I have developed a simple client and server application using winsock API in C++ where the client sends hello message to the server. But, I want to send multiple images to server at once from the client socket. I don't know how to send image files using socket programming. Please help me with sending of multiple image files at once using winsock.

My code is as under:

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

static void ClientApp()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    SOCKET server;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.100.4");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5555);

    connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    cout << "Connected to server!" << endl;

    char buffer[1024] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
    send(server, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    cout << "Message sent!" << endl;

    closesocket(server);
    WSACleanup();
    cout << "Socket closed." << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ClientApp();
}
```

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

static void ServerApp()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;

    SOCKET server, client;

    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr, clientAddr;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(5555);

    bind(server, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    listen(server, 0);

    cout << "Listening for incoming connections..." << endl;

    char buffer[1024];
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if ((client = accept(server, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
        recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        cout << "Client says: " << buffer << endl;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        closesocket(client);
        cout << "Client disconnected." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ServerApp();
}
```

Comment: Open an image file, read contents and send it over to server along with name. You need to decide format of packet I.e. name, buffer, buffer length should be part of packet.

Comment: I have to send multiple image files at a time

Comment: Off topic: `send(server, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` buffer is 1024 bytes. `sizeof(buffer)` returns the full size of the buffer. You are sending WAY more than just "Hello." Fortunately you are reading 1024 at the other end.

Comment: @user4581301 When the client application runs, then I have to select multiple image files from a folder and send those together to server. I need help with sending of multiple images, not only one image

Comment: @user4581301 Ultimately your files will go one by one. Whatever protocol you decide has to be repeated for N times to send N files. I dont suggest sending image files as zip as compression may not help much.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai What approach should I follow?

Comment: Send some header information so you can tell one image from the next. Open the image file. Read some of the image file and write it to the socket and repeat until all of the file has been read and sent.Then repeat until you have sent all of the files. Receiver reads the header and loops on `recv` until it receives the whole file. Store the file and wait for header signifying new file. Repeat until all files have been received.